# order of execution confusion

Tags: sql, postgresql, order-of-execution

```
SELECT First_name,last_name,email,ROUND (AVG(Amount),2) AS moneyspent
FROM Customer INNER JOIN Payment
ON Customer.customer_id= Payment.customer_id
WHERE Staff_id=2 
GROUP BY First_name,last_name,email
HAVING SUM(Amount)>100
ORDER BY Moneyspent DESC
```

| first_name | last_name | email | moneyspent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brittany | Riley | brittany.riley@sakilacustomer.org | 5.83 |
| Arnold | Havens | arnold.havens@sakilacustomer.org | 5.14 |
| Eleanor | Hunt | eleanor.hunt@sakilacustomer.org | 5.04 |
| Stacey | Montgomery | stacey.montgomery@sakilacustomer.org | 4.73 |
| Karl | Seal | karl.seal@sakilacustomer.org | 4.63 |

I am confused about the Order of execution.  I understand we cannot filter based on an aggregated result like `AVG(Amount)` in `WHERE` because that hasn't been executed yet. Does `AVG(Amount)` happen at the `GROUP BY` or `SELECT`?

1. If it happens at `GROUP BY`, there should be three columns `First_name`, `Last_name`, `email` and `AVG(Amount)` left. How can `HAVING SUM(AMOUNT)` still be executing?
2. If it happens at `SELECT`, then how come we can still filter using `AVG(Amount)` at `HAVING`, as `HAVING` comes before `SELECT`?

Comment: HAVING is executed **after** the select, that is why you can use AVG or SUM

Answer (score 1):

When processing your `GROUP BY` the query execution engine will also evaluate `SUM(Amount)` (as well as `AVG(Amount)`) for each first_name, last_name, email combination; because these are referred to by your SELECT and HAVING, respectively. Some RDBMSs don't allow `HAVING` referring to an expression not already on the SELECT clause, but I guess PostgreSql is doing us a favour and allowing it. For your purposes you should assume that those aggregations are calculated at the GROUP BY time (HAVING is applied afterwards; but this is really a 'logical ' order, because the engine can apply parts of it earlier if it deduces it would be cheaper and that it wouldn't change results).

Comment: Thank you so much.  This clears up my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses can be thought of as evaluated *before* the `SELECT` clauses for when considering what the result would be, but any aggregate functions used in `SELECT` column definitions still have access to the underlying disaggregated data.

The order to think about it is:

1. `JOIN`s and `WHERE` clause
2. `GROUP BY`; note that however, you can also group by columns in the output query, e.g. `GROUP BY 1, 2` but this is syntatic sugar
3. `HAVING`
4. `SELECT`

You can see that the actual calculation of the resulting columns occurs last because if you use a window function as part of the `SELECT` to access (for example) the previous row you can only access data that you have either included in `GROUP BY` or that uses an aggregate function, and data removed by the `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause is filtered out.